# c pass a string to function then return a string

Tags: c

After exploring the internet, i've wrote the following script, but still got errors, anyone knows what the errors are?( the line with //err)

```
typedef struct name_value_set {
    char name[250]; 
    char value[250]; 
} nv_set;

char * getInput2(char *param) {
    char *my_data=0;
    int data_len;
    char *tmp_ptr, *tmp;
    int i;
    nv_set *nv;

    data_len=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    char field[data_len]; 

    my_data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(data_len+1));
    fread(my_data,1,data_len,stdin);

    i=0;
    while (my_data[0]!='\0') {
     tmp=split(my_data,'='); // err
     makespace(tmp); 
     tmp=convert(tmp); // err
     strcpy(nv[i].name,tmp); // 
     tmp=split(my_data,'&'); //err 
     makespace(tmp); // 
     tmp=convert(tmp); // err
     strcpy(nv[i].value,tmp); // 
     i++;
    }
    i--; // 

    int j=0;
    for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
    if(nv[j].name == param) {
        return nv[j].value;
    }


}


void makespace(char *s)
{
    int i,len;
    len=strlen(s);

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
      if (s[i]=='+')
        s[i]=' ';
    }
}

char *split(char *s, char stop)
{
    char *data;
    char *tmp;
    int i,len,j;

    len=strlen(s);
    tmp=s;
    data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
       if (s[i]!=stop)
         data[i]=s[i]; // 
      else {
        i+=1; // 
          break;
       } 
    }
    data[i]='\0';
    for (j=i;j<len;j++)
      s[j-i]=tmp[j];
      s[len-i]='\0';
     return data;
}


char *convert(char *s)
{
    int x,y,len;
    char *data;

    len=strlen(s);
    data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    y=0;
    for (x=0;x<len;x++) {
    if (s[x]!='%') {
        data[y]=s[x]; // 
          y++;
      }
    else {

        data[y]=(char)(16*hexa(s[x+1])+hexa(s[x+2]));
        y++;
        x=x+2;
      }
    }
     data[y]='\0';
     return data;
}


int hexa(char c)
{
    switch(c) {
    case '0':return 0;
    case '1':return 1;
    case '2':return 2;
    case '3':return 3;
    case '4':return 4;
    case '5':return 5;
    case '6':return 6;
    case '7':return 7;
    case '8':return 8;
    case '9':return 9;
    case 'A':return 10;
    case 'B':return 11;
    case 'C':return 12;
    case 'D':return 13;
    case 'E':return 14;
    case 'F':return 15;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't be vague, be an ace; write a proper test-case!  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints http://sscce.org/ http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml

Comment: You don't say what the error is, but you may just need to forward declare your functions.  The compiler parses your file in order and when it's compiling your first function it hasn't "seen" split() yet.  So put `extern char *split(char *, char);` at the top and see if that helps.  (repeat for other functions, of course)

Comment: "still got errors"  Well, what kind of errors?  Are they compiler errors?  Does it compile?  If so, can you run it?  Does it crash?  Does it not work correctly?  Have you tried attaching a debugger to see what is wrong with it?

Comment: all errors are "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: What is this "script" supposed to do and what errors are you seeing?

Comment: what has your problem to do with the title of your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding prototypes for the functions "makespace", "split", "convert" and "hexa" at the beginning of your code; I expect what you're seeing is the result of implicitly declared functions conflicting with the function definitions.  Also, just to be sure, you're including stdio.h and string.h in your source file, right?

Comment: i've find out my_data got nothing~ have any ideas? 
data_len=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
my_data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(data_len+1));
fread(my_data,1,data_len,stdin);

Comment: Okay, "my_data got nothing" is a little ambiguous, and I think it is entirely unrelated to the original question, but let's have at it anyway.  I'm going to assume you mean 'my_data' is NULL after the 'malloc'.  You may wish to confirm that the environment variable CONTENT_LENGTH is in fact set to a sane value, or even set at all.