# c string version of atoi

Tags: c

is there any functions like atoi read the buffer to return a string?

```
fgets(input, data_len, stdin);
return atoi(input + 6); // i need the string
```

thanks

full code

```
char *getInput2(char *param) {
    data_len=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    char input[data_len];
    fgets(input, data_len, stdin);

    char *r_str;
    strcpy (r_str, input+6);

    return r_str;
}
```

finally, internal server error........

```
char *getInput2(char *param) {

    char input[100];
    data_len=sizeof(input);
    fgets(input, data_len, stdin);


    return strdup (input+7);
}
```

only can return first char......enter 12 only return 1, what's the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Here is my theory: he wants to return a substring of the input (input+6). This fails because it's a local variable. He knows he can return the value successfully as an int, using atoi. Now he wants the same for strings (i.e. strings-by-value). He doesn't know that these really don't exist in C. The most literal answer would be "strdup".

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and the output you would expect? Your question isn't very clear. Something like  getInput2("hello world") should return " world" would be very helpful.

Comment: In support of Martin's interpretation, note his earlier question [c pass a string to function then return a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066873/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking but if it's how to get the string representation of the integer at offset 6, you can do it as a two-step:

```
char str[enough_to_hold_datalen_and_then_some];
int val = atoi (input+6);
sprintf (str, "%d", val);
```

Alternatively, if you want to get a chunk of the string regardless of whether it's made up of digits:

```
strcpy (str, input+6);                      // get the rest of the string
strncpy (str, input+6, 4); str[4] = '\0';   // get up to four characters.
```

If your problem is that input is a local variable to the function and, when you return its address, you get bogus data because it's gone out of scope, I'd use:

```
return strdup (input+6);
```

That will return a copy of the string on the heap (which is long-lived as opposed to the stack frame, which is not).

Just remember that you  need to `free` that memory when you're finished with it. And be certain that you actually *have* six characters in that buffer.

If your C implementation doesn't have a `strdup`, use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802).

---

Based on your update, it looks like you're after that last option. With your code:

```
char *r_str;
strcpy (r_str, input+6);
return r_str;
```

you are not actually allocating any storage to put the string copy (hence the crash). I would replace that whole bit with a simple:

```
return strdup (input+6);
```

as I suggested.

---

Ha, ha, gotta love those [Linux man page writers](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy):

> If the destination string of a strcpy() is not large enough (that is, if the programmer was stupid/lazy, and failed to check the size before copying) then anything might happen. Overflowing fixed length strings is a favourite cracker technique.

Comment: @friends, see the last few (string-related) options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return the string, then atoi has nothing to do with it. Instead, your problem is that you cannot return memory of a local variable. Returning memory in C is always difficult; typically, you return dynamically allocated memory and expect the caller to free it:

```
char* get_value()
{
    char input[100];
    int data_len = sizeof(input);
    char *result;
    fgets(input, data_len, stdin);
    result = malloc(strlen(input)-5); /* reserve enough memory, including the terminating NUL */
    strcpy(result, input+6);
    return result;
}
```

(you can shorten this by using strdup)

Alternatively, you can use a global variable, but that won't be reentrant:

```
char input[100];
char* get_value()
{
    int data_len = sizeof(input);
    fgets(input, data_len, stdin);
    return input+6;
}
```